# magick annotate picture with arrows

Tags: r, magick-r-package

I need to add a arrow to a picture.  Currently I'm using the code below but I want to make the arrow longer.

```
library(magick)
tiger <- image_read_svg('http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg', width = 400)
print(tiger)

tiger  %>%
  image_annotate(., "Tiger's mouth", size = 15, color = "red",
  boxcolor = "gold", degrees = 00, location = "+196+250", font = 'Times') %>% 
  image_annotate( sprintf('\u2191'), size = 15, color = "red",
  boxcolor = "gold", degrees = 270, location = "+180+265")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the `size` should do it

```r
library(magick)
tiger <- image_read_svg('http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg', width = 400)
print(tiger)

tiger  %>%
  image_annotate(., "Tiger's mouth", size = 20, color = "red",
                 boxcolor = "gold", degrees = 00, location = "+250+250", 
                 font = 'Times') %>% 
  image_annotate( sprintf('\u2191'), size = 50, color = "blue",
                  boxcolor = "transparent", degrees = 270, location = "+190+275")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).